# How to define angular1.3+ controller in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-controller

In new version of angular you must define controller like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

How can I define This code by TypeScript?

Comment: Have a look at this article.. http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/writing-cleaner-angularjs-with-typescript-and-controlleras/ It might help

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller will be something like:

```
class myCtrl
{
  constructor( $scope )
  {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  }
}
```

And with module it will be something like

```
module myApp{

    export class myCtrl{

     static $inject = ["$scope"];

        constructor( $scope: any)
      {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
      }
    }
}
```

$inject method specify the parameters that angular will inject in the class constructor. like $scope in our example you can inject services etc also

Now you can use it as

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl',myApp.myCtrl);
```

Comment: What about $scope injection?

Comment: @estus is it right now? plz improve it if i am missing something as i am also learning 2.0 and typescript

Comment: @A.B tnx...Can you explane about  static $inject = ["$scope"]; in your answer

Comment: @A.B I have an build error on  this line "angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl',myApp.myCtrl);"  that say "Could not find symbol 'angular'"...I add this line in TypeScript File

Comment: add angular-mocks.d.ts and then try

Comment: No.angular-mocks.d.ts depend to angular.d.ts  and when I add this to my project I get many build error..I find out that my TypeScript version is 1.1 and  angular.d.ts file write by 1.4 ..I must update from  vs2012 to 2013 and install TypeScript 1.4